# Открыть gnome terminal

Tags: c++, linux, c

Какие есть функции или системные вызовы для открытия `gnome terminal`? Нужно не через консоль, а именно в программе на С, чтобы получить файловый дескриптор и перенаправить в новый терминал вывод программы.

Comment: обычный [exec](https://www.opennet.ru/cgi-bin/opennet/man.cgi?topic=exec&category=3) не подходит?

Comment: @KoVadim при вызове `exec` родительский процесс прекращает свою работу. Реализовать через fork-exec не получится, так как надо реализовать однопоточное приложение.

Comment: В линусе запуск любого (да да, кроме init)  - это fork+exec. По другому нельзя.
И fork не делает программу "многопоточной".

Comment: @KoVadim просто мне дали задание, и там было сказано представить, что мы делаем программу на некоторой встроенной системе, где нет поддержки многопоточности. То есть вызовы `fork()` и `pthread()` не допускаются

Comment: fork и exec  - это не многопоточность. И если на этой системе удалось запусть gnome-terminal, то fork exec там будут работать.

Comment: Какие-то очень противоречивые данные.

Comment: @RomanMarkov запустить gnome-terminal без fork+exec (`system` и `posix_spawn` считайте сахаром, которые прячут fork+exec внутри) из своей программы - нельзя. Это и есть те самые системные вызовы. Посмотрите мой ответ - дополнил максимально близким желаемым поведением. Ну и VTE в вашем случае выглядит наиболее логичным шагом - тут точно не вызывается форков... кроме как для shell :-D

Comment: @Monah Tuk спасибо, попробую разобраться

Answer (score 1):

Системных вызовов для этого нет. Не системная это функциональность.

Можно воспользоваться: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Pipe-to-a-Subprocess.html, но это позволит вам отправлять команды на stdin терминала, т.е. он будет выполнять каждую строчку как команду, а не просто выводить на экран вывод вашей программы.

Ещё можно сделать ход конём, сделав fork+exec(gnome-terminal), передав ему самого себя как параметр для запуска. Примерно такое должно получиться:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    // Run from GUI! Restart in terminal

    if (!isatty(fileno(stdin)))
    {
        auto pid = fork();
        if (pid == 0)
        {
            vector<char*> args = {
                ::strdup("gnome-terminal"),
                ::strdup("-e"),
            };

            // Dup my commad line options to the terminal
            for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
            {
                args.push_back(argv[i]);
            }

            args.push_back(nullptr);

            if (execvp("gnome-terminal", args.data()) < 0)
                exit(1);
        }
        exit(pid < 0 ? 1 : 0);
    }

    // Regular execution
    cout << "Hello, from the terminal!\n";
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Ещё стоит рассмотреть возможность использования [VTE](https://developer.gnome.org/vte/)

Ну и последний вариант, по результатам уточнённых данных:

1. Запускаете терминал (как? если вам зепрещён форк? `posix_spawn`, по сути, тот же fork+exec внутри).
2. В родительском процессе у вас остаётся его PID
3. Терминал открывает PTS устройство (/dev/pts/###) которое используется для IO
4. Смотрим в /proc/TERMINAL-PID/fd куда ссылаются дескрипторы 0, 1 и 2 (можно только 1)
5. В своей программе открываем эти файлы для записи, запомниаем дескрипторы (пусть будет 1 - `fd`)
6. Закрываем свои дескрипторы 1 и 2 (`close(1); close(2);`)
7. Используем `dup2` что бы замапить `fd` на дескрипторы 1 и 2.
8. Весь наш вывод на STDOUT и STDERR теперь идёт в окно терминала.
9. Но зачем?